# Calendar events showing all dates for that day

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I am using a pretty standard calendar for handling events for a site I am making. I didn't change anything from the default, but this is happening.

Here is an image of the calendar view from the views ui: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq3mh.jpg
Here is the actual output on the page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTSuf.jpg

I see what it is doing. It is spitting out all of the dates on that day for each event. I just can't figure out how to make it stop.

Comment: That looks like the default behavior -- what did you want it to do instead?

Comment: Are you using multivalue fields for your dates? Views cannot remove certain duplications in multivalue fields, however, you can remove them using theme pre-rendering. This has been discussed at: https://drupal.org/node/1223448. Let me know whether this fits your problem, and I'll add an answer that's more verbose.

Comment: @anschauung - Look at it again. The first screen shot is correct. Event 1 is showing its date, Event 2 is showing its date, Event 3 is showing its date. But in the rendered view, Event 1 is showing its date and the date for Event 2 and the date for event three. Event 2 is showing all three dates and Event 3 is showing all three. That's normal?

Comment: @Ursula - Thanks. I'll give it a try and let you know.